I am unable to get the script to click on this span tag. It doesn't give me any error in the terminal when I run it as well
I am creating a script that automates uploads onto a site. Here, I have to upload images, enter descriptions etc. At the end, i have to click on a save button. This button is, however, a span tag, as seen in the screenshot below :
Code when inspect element is clicked on the submit button
This is the code for the span button
<div class="btnContainer"> == $0
<span id="saveBasic" class="slCatBtn activeNow" style="position:relative">
**"Save and Continue"**
<span id="saveBasicArrow" class="saveBasicArrow" style="display: inline-bl ock;"></span>
<span id="saveBasicLoader" class="loader" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; margin-left: 4px; left: 160px; display: none;"></span>
</span>
</div>
<span id="saveBasicError" class="error" style="display: none;position: relativ e;float: right;"></span>
</div>
</div>

I have to click on the save and continue button
I have used this code :
submit_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Save and Continue')]")
submit_btn.click()
It doesn't give me any error, but it doesn't work as well. I have tried giving
By.ID,"saveBasic"
By.CLASS_NAME."slCatBtn"
No error nor output comes.

(By.ID,"saveBasic") is your best bet. Can you post a link to the page? I don't know what we're going to be able to do with this if we can't see the page. You aren't surrounding this code with a try-except that is eating exceptions, are you?

@JeffC Hey, I got it to work using //span[normalize-space()="Save and Continue"]
